# Trouble with alternating string case

Tags: python, string, algorithm, function, loops

Working through exercises on the CodeWars website and I need help being pointed in the right direction for a simple function:

> Write a function toWeirdCase (weirdcase in Ruby) that accepts a
>   string, and returns the same string with all even indexed characters
>   in each word upper cased, and all odd indexed characters in each word
>   lower cased. The indexing just explained is zero based, so the
>   zero-ith index is even, therefore that character should be upper
>   cased.
>
> The passed in string will only consist of alphabetical characters and
>   spaces(' '). Spaces will only be present if there are multiple words.
>   Words will be separated by a single space(' ').

The code I have so far is this:

```
def to_weird_case(string):
    #TODO
    new_string = ''
    add = 0 
    for letter in range(len(string)):
        if string[letter] == ' ':
            add += 1
            new_string += string[letter]
            continue

        if (letter+add)%2 == 0:
            new_string += string[letter].upper()
        else:
            new_string += string[letter].lower()

    print("Returning: " + new_string)
    return new_string
```

I am trying to iterate over each letter while taking in to account the spaces but I am unsure how to 'skip over' the spaces and that is what is messing up my function? If someone could point me in the right direction that would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Nice question, there is a few good tools you can use ;), In your case I would use enumerate instead the counter

Comment: Plus +1 for mentioning enumerate @DamianLattenero

Answer (score 2):

```
def to_weird_case(string):
    #TODO
    counter = 0
    new_string = ''
    add = 0 
    for letter in range(len(string)):
        if string[letter] == ' ':
            new_string += string[letter]
            continue

        if (counter)%2 == 0:
             new_string += string[letter].upper()
        else:
            new_string += string[letter].lower()
        # Increment counter after one place as 0th position is even
        counter = counter + 1
    print("Returning: " + new_string)
    return new_string


to_weird_case("HELLO MY NAME IS abcdefghijk")
```

**Output : Returning: HeLlO mY nAmE iS aBcDeFgHiJk**

Answer (score 1):

Just create a counter (an integer variable) that will keep track of whether you are in an even or odd index. The counter will not increment if you encounter a space, thereby ignoring it.

```
def to_weird_case(string):
    #TODO
    counter = 0
    new_string = ''
    add = 0 
    for letter in range(len(string)):
        if string[letter] == ' ':
            new_string += string[letter]
            continue

        # Increment counter only if not space
        counter = counter + 1
        if (counter)%2 == 0:
             new_string += string[letter].upper()
        else:
            new_string += string[letter].lower()

        print("Returning: " + new_string)
        return new_string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disregard the spaces by first *splitting* the string using `str.split`, transform each word using `enumerate` to select even and odd characters, and then rejoin the string using `str.join` on spaces:

```
def transform_word(s):
    return ''.join(x.upper() if i%2==0 else x.lower() for i, x in enumerate(s))
    #                        ^------------^-> ternary operator for alternating

def to_weird_case(string):
    return ' '.join(transform_word(s) for s in string.split())

print(to_weird_case('This is a lovely day'))
# ThIs Is A LoVeLy DaY
```

And if you eventually want to consider the spaces, use the `transform_word` function directly:

```
print(transform_word('This is a lovely day'))
# ThIs iS A LoVeLy dAy
```

Comment: Moses the expert voice, always present in python issues. Nice answer as always

Answer (score 1):

Try **list comprehension**:

```
def my_func(your_string):
    x = [ x.upper() if i%2==0 else x.lower() for i,x in enumerate(your_string)]
    return ''.join(x)

your_string = 'hello my name is lmurdock12'
print(my_func(your_string))
```

Output:

```
HeLlO My nAmE Is lMuRdOcK12
```

So basically what happens in this list comprehension is that we use enumerate()

```
x = [ x.upper() if i%2==0 else x.lower() for i,x in enumerate(your_string)]
```

enumerate takes a iterable (string,list..etc) and gives out items one by one (i) where i would be 0,1,2,3...and so on

So in the list comprehension we check if `i` corresponding to that item `x` returned from iterable string `your_list`. So in `hello my name is lmurdock12` i would be `0`  for `h` and `1` for `e` and so on. If `i%2==0` which means it's even we keep `x.upper()` else we keep `x.lower()` in the list.

Finally use `''.join(x)` to join the list and return it if you want.

**NOTE:** This could be done without enumerate by using `index()` but that would make our algorithm a little inefficient because that we way we have search for the value and return index everytime. It's better to use enumerate.

Comment: Beautiful answer! I'm trying to understand list comprehension but I'm a little far :/

Comment: Try learning and using it wherever you can. TRUST me it can be very helpful. Magical things in python.

Comment: Good advice, thanks , that's why my answer, the one above, was about a parallel solution to the for loop

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution. Hope that helps!

```
def to_weird_case(string)
  words = string.split(" ")

  words.map do |word|
    word.chars.map.with_index {|letter, idx| idx.even? ? letter.upcase : letter.downcase }.join("")
  end.join(" ")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the counter if you user the enumerate function

```
def to_weird_case(string):
    #TODO
    new_string = ''
    for i,letter in enumerate(string):
        if string[i] == ' ':
            new_string += string[i]
            continue

        if i%2 == 0:
            new_string += string[i].upper()
        else:
            new_string += string[i].lower()

    print("Returning: " + new_string)
    return new_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not really pythonesque. Your function can actually have only 1 line of code. This is why Python is so cool.

```
def ToWeirdCase(word):
    return ''.join([char.upper() if pos%2==0 else char.lower() for pos, char in enumerate(word)])
```

Comment: You need to return a string not a list so use `join()` also why do you need `and char != " "` this line? No use.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had this same problem early this morning, this is my answer:

```
def to_weird_case(sentence):
counter = 0 # Counter set to zero, because of the even number fact at zero-ith.
weird_sentence = "" # This is the string we are going to return at the end.
for character in sentence:
    if character == " " and counter % 2 == 0: 
        weird_sentence += character 
        counter += 1    # Incrementation that will now make each characters before a space to be uppercased.
    elif character != " " and counter % 2 == 0:
        weird_sentence += character.upper() 
    else:
        weird_sentence += character.lower()
    counter += 1
return weird_sentence
```

I hope it helps you out.